# Laposta API - Get Subscriber Total

Tags: php

After downloading the PHP Wrapper from github (https://github.com/laposta/laposta-api-php) I get a blank response when running the code below on WordPress.

The API returns the correct data when used in a PHP file.

I'm sure this is a simple error on my part, can anyone give me a pointer? I used the API doc's and the provided example, so not really sure why this is not working correctly.

```
require_once(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/laposta/lib/Laposta.php');
Laposta::setApiKey("MY_API_KEY");
Laposta::setHttpsDisableVerifyPeer(true);

$list = new Laposta_List();

$result = $list->get("MY_LIST_ID");
$members = $result['list']['members']['active'];
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. Seems I cam just use relative path for the `require_once`.